# Find the points of relative extrema of $f(x)=x^x$

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

I have to find the points of relative extrema of $f(x)=x^x$ and $f'(x)=x^x(lnx+1)$ .

After setting $f'(x)=0$ , I found the point of relative minima at $x=1/e$ but I cannot find the point of relative maxima.

Besides the first and second derivative tests, are there any quicker methods ?

Comment: There is no relative maxima.

Comment: When $x> \frac 1e$ the function is strictly increasing and there is no relative maxima.  When $x<0$ the function ceases to be continuous in the real numbers.

Comment: Try to plot the graph of $f(x)=x^x$, that function increases infinitely

Comment: @Travish The answers states $x=e$ for relative max but l can't get there.

Comment: @Sango Yes, that makes sense. It keep getting bigger exponentially so there shouldn't be a max.

Comment: @AristotleStagiritis in that way you can't find a "global" max